# CollectionView numberOfItemsInSection - Swift

Tags: swift

I want to determine numberOfItemsInSection based on the data contained in the "KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM" Array. For example; KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM [0] = 3, KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM [1] = 4. So the first section should be 3 items, 2.section should be 4 items. How can I do that?

```
    var KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM = [String]()

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM.count
 }

@objc func dene(){ ...
              if let baslik = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] {
                            for review in baslik {
                            if let soru_baslik = review["TOPLAM"] as? Int {
                            let s = String(describing: soru_baslik)
                                self.KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM.append(s)
                                } }
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.sonsuzCollec.reloadData()  }   } }
```

Comment: Not related but: Name you variables starting with a lowercase, and not all in uppercase if possible `KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM` => `kategoriDavtoplam` (or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return  Int(KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM[section])?? 0
 }
```

Comment: see the updated answer, you have the string array of array.

Comment: I collect in the database directly count number. CATEGORY AND TOTAL ["3", "4"] so there are 3 items and 4 items as you spread. How do I print this to count?

Comment: do you mean your KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM = ["3","4"] ??

Comment: Yes, but he says that the numbers 3 and 4 inside are 3 items and 4 items. In other words, what you wrote is in numerical form.

Comment: try return  Int(KATEGORIDAVTOPLAM[section])?? 0